# Strange behavior using math.pow() on dart vm

Tags: dart

Is someone else is having this problem in Dart vm? What is going wrong?

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  print ( math.pow( 2, 60 ) ); // -> 1152921504606846976
  print ( math.pow( 2, 61 ) ); // -> 2305843009213693952
  print ( math.pow( 2, 62 ) ); // -> -4611686018427387904
  print ( math.pow( 2, 63 ) ); // -> -9223372036854775808
  print ( math.pow( 2, 64 ) ); // -> 18446744073709551616
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in Math.pow and large numbers: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8259

John